# Full-text query returns no results

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, full-text-search

everyone! 
I would be very pleased if anyone could help me out.

I've developed a full-text search engine with C# and Sql Server 2008 as a DB. 
The query below returns results when I run it in SSMS, but it returns nothing when I run it from C# code with its parameterized form:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct occurrence "+
                                "FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @doc)', 1033, 0, 0) "+
                                "where display_term in "+
                                "( "+
                                  "SELECT display_term "+
                                  "FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @searchterm)', 1033, 0, 0) "+
                                 ")",conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchterm",SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchterm"].Value = "distributed property";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@doc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@doc"].Value = "in the search of distributed ways that are provided by properties";
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: 1) start up SQL Server Profiler, 2) run your app, 3) capture the exact query, 4) debug in SQL Management Studio

Comment: Are you setting your command type? May I suggest considering a stored procedure?

Comment: @BrianP The CommandType is set to default, i.e. it is=CommandType.Text

Comment: @BrianP If I use a stored procedure, then how can I retrieve result set in C# code? I thought a store procedure does not return any results, it just performs some operations.

Comment: You can perform a select in your stored procedure and the results will be returned.  It is nothing more than a predefined set of commands that have a name.

Comment: Are you sure it returns nothing? I don't see anything in your code that shows what you do with dr after the call to ExecuteReader? Maybe look at the HasRows property or look at using while(dr.Read()) in a debugger to see it actually has returned data.

Comment: @MrMoose yes of course I am checking dr.HasRows property afterwards, and it is false

Comment: @TimMedora Unfortunately I am using Sql Server 2008 Express, so I don't have such a tool..

Comment: @TimMedora I installed free Express Profiler by Codeplex, traced the query: `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT distinct occurrence 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(''FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @doc)'', 1033, 0, 0) 
where display_term in ( 
SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(''FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @searchterm)'', 1033, 0, 0) )',
N'@searchterm varchar(20),@doc varchar(65)',@searchterm='distributed property',@doc='in the search of distributed ways that are provided by properties'
` It does not return result in SSMS also. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Without seeing your data source, it's impossible to say. At least you have eliminated the c# portion of the application and can debug it further. I would simplify the query as much as possible, and then add pieces back in until it stops returning the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Does cleaning it up a bit with this help point out any differences between your in VS code from your SQL code? Also, please, use USING and ADDWITHVALUE when creating your queries. I don't know if it's just me, but this is a MUST in my opinion.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    string command = string.Format({0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5},  
    "SELECT distinct occurrence ",
    "FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @doc)', 1033, 0, 0) ",
    "where display_term in "
    "( ",
    "SELECT display_term ",
    "FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @searchterm)', 1033, 0, 0) ",
    ")")
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command,conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchterm", "distributed property");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc", "in the search of distributed ways that are provided by properties");

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        using (SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader(cmd))
        {
            if(dr.HasRows)
            {
                While(dr.Read())
                {
                    // Do stuff here...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```